# Java 8 for Sonar, PMD, Findbugs and Checkstyle in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube, pmd

I have upgraded to Java 8 and when I try to run the task sonarRunner in order to get the reports I get the following message.

> Execution failed for task ':sonarRunner'.
>
> org.sonar.api.utils.XmlParserException: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unsupported Java version for PMD: 1.8

Is Java 8 supported in PMD? If yes how can I solve this problem?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since version 5.1.0, they have had Java 8 support: [See Changelists here](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.3/changelog-old.html).

I am not an active Sonar user, but from what I could find, there has been some limitation of Sonar support for Java 8.  It looks like you need a more recent version of SonarQube, and version 2.2.0 or higher of the PMD plugin: [read here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PMD+Plugin)

Comment: And I do confirm that you should use: the latest 2.4 version of the SonarQube Java plugin, the latest 3.0 version of the SonarQube Findbugs plugin and the latest 2.2 version of the PMD plugin.